# check for valid number input - console application

Tags: c#

I have a little problem with a simple console application in which i would like to detect if the user inputs a correctly formatted numerical value. 
That is, values such as 1212sss or anything like asjkq12323 or a single character is not accepted. I would like to only accept pure integer values.

Here is what i have tried

```
bool detectNumber(string s)
{
   int value=0;
   Int.TryParse(s,out value);
   return (value!=0)?true:false;
}
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you soooo much,,,,,

Comment: And what's the problem with what you have tried?

Comment: I wouldn't write a method to do **exactly** what `int.TryParse` does...

Comment: Actually there is nothing wrong at all over there, I only would like to share a result of tryparse.

Comment: @Hoger. So... You didn't have any question ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string line = Console.ReadLine(); 
int value;
if (int.TryParse(line, out value)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Integer here!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`TryParse` returns a boolean. Check that, not the value passed via the out parameter.

```
if( int.TryParse( s, out value ) )
{
  // do something
}
```

Or just:

```
return int.TryParse( s, out value );
```

Incidentally, it is not necessary to initialize a value passed using the `out` keyword. The method declaring the parameter must initialize it before returning.

```
int foo; // legal
int.TryParse( "123", out foo );
```

All BCL "Try" methods follow the same convention (such as [double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) for floating point numbers, as @gdoron mentioned in the comments).

And for the curious, [source code](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid3C52C0D806349C6FB2E0802CB444C53B35853491.aspx) for the underlying library which implements int.TryParse().

Answer (score 2):

```
int value = 0;
bool ok = int.TryParse(s, out value);
return ok;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to test for only numeric numbers:

first of all, never use `Int` because of it's maximum value, either use `int` or `Int32`.

## Parse

```
int result;
if (int.TryParse("123", out result))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Valid integer: " + result);
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Not a valid integer");
}
```

## Convert.ToInt32()

```
// throws ArgumentNullExceptionint
result1 = Int32.Parse(null);

// doesn't throw an exception, returns 0
int result2 = Convert.ToInt32(null);
```

## IsNumeric()

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
// ......
bool result = Information.IsNumeric("123");
```

## Pattern Matching

```
string strToTest = "123";
Regex reNum = new Regex(@"^\d+$");
bool isNumeric = reNum.Match(strToTest).Success;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works normal, you can only refactor it a bit. Following code is shorter but does exactly the same:

```
static bool IsInt32(string s)
{
    int value;
    return Int32.TryParse(s, out value);
}
```